# What is the reason why it is haram to dye one's hair black?

Tags: halal-haram, hadith-interpretation, hair, dyeing-hair

The Prophet Muhammad (SAWS) said to a person who had white hair:

> “Change this white hair but avoid black.” Saheeh Muslim (5476

The Prophet also said:

> “There will be people at the end of time who will dye their hair black like the crops of pigeons; they will not even smell the fragrance of Paradise.” Narrated by Abu Dawood (4212) and al-Nasaa’i (8/138); classed as saheeh by al-Albaani in Saheeh al-Jaami’ (8153).

These hadith indicates that dying your hair black is haram but what is the reason that it is haram? Why did the Prophet forbid it?